# Can't access .mdf on IIS, only on IIS local

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am able to access a .mdf file on local IIS. However, when I move it to the server under app_data, I can't. Am I missing a step?

Additional Information

1. The .mdf is under app_data on the server.
2. It appears like it is trying to connect, but cannot.
3. Connection string is as follows:

   ```
    Public Const SQL_PRO As String = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\MyDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
   ```

Update 2

Here is the Error Message. Sql Express 2008 is installed on IIS

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.)

Thanks,

Eric

Comment: What is the exact error message? Is Sql Server installed on the server?

Comment: Updated the question with the error

Comment: Look at this text from the error: `" Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.)"`

Comment: Do I need to attach the database via Management studio for an Express database? I do specify the location (attachdbfilename) in my connection string. Do I need to allow remote connections? I did install the LocalDB addin.

Comment: Maybe, but that message indicates that Sql Server wasn't even available on the server to make the attempt in the first place.

Comment: It is installed and the SQL Service Express service is running on the server. I just checked the Sql Configuration Manager.

Answer (score 0):

In your VS Project, in solution explorer, choose the MDF and choose properties (Alt+Enter), for Copy to Output Directory, choose Copy Always.  Im thinking your file isn't packaged when publishing.

Comment: It is on the server. I also looked under IIS's features and do not see a separate one for Sql Express. I was not sure if a feature needed to be added. Permissions look fine as well.